# Rails 3 Model Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models: Users, which belongs to Concerts, which belongs to Regions. A User listening to a Concert in a Region. Model belongs_to relationships set up respectively.

In the Concerts controller, I count the number of Users listening to a Concert like this:

```
@listeners = @concert.users.count
```

However, I want to list the number of listeners per concert at the region level. In my Region controller I want to do something like this:

`@all_listeners = @region.concert.users.count`. The number of listeners of each concert, in each region. I know this code is not correct but that is the general idea. Any point in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `has_many :through` to your Region class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :concert
end

class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :users
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
  has_many :users, :through => :concerts
end
```

Then you can count the users in a region as so:

```
@all_listeners = @region.users.count
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, that was it. How would you count per concert?

@all_listeners = @region.users.count(params[:id])?

Comment: The first example in your question has the listeners-for-a-concert count.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me: 

@listeners = @region.users.count(:group=>:concert_id)